# How to make an raycast cant detect some colliders in unity 3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a FPS game in unity, I am using Raycast shooting technique, but when I am looking down the Raycast detects player, So I want my raycast to can't collide player layer . But I don't know how to do that

Comment: [`Physics.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) -> `layerMask: A Layer mask that is used to selectively ignore Colliders when casting a ray.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution to the problem would be to change the layer of the player gameobject to the 'ignore raycast' layer.

You can do this by selecting the player object in the inspector, clicking the layer drop down menu and selecting ignore raycast.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a variable like :

`public LayerMask layerMask`

And in the inspector select only the layer you want to use the RayCast and then.

`if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, layerMask)`

Where ray is your Ray and hit is the RaycastHit but you can do with anything

Answer (score 0):

### Change the player layer then ignore that layer in your raycast code